# how to sum 2d array

Tags: php, foreach

Good evening

I have a question here. i have two arrays: $duration_c[$k][$s]. it prints all ok

```
$duration_c[0][0]="19:30:00";
$duration_c[0][1]="00:10:00";

$duration_c[1][0]="00:30:00";
$duration_c[1][1]="00:20:00";
```

than to sum

```
$times=$duration_c[$k][$s];
function sum_the_time($times) {

  $seconds = 0;
  foreach ($times as $time)
  {
    list($hour,$minute,$second) = explode(':', $time);
    $seconds += $hour*3600;
    $seconds += $minute*60;
    $seconds += $second;
 }
  $hours = floor($seconds/3600);
  $seconds -= $hours*3600;
  $minutes  = floor($seconds/60);
  $seconds -= $minutes*60;
  // return "{$hours}:{$minutes}:{$seconds}";
  return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
} 
echo sum_the_time($times);
```

how to sum $duration_c[0][0]+$duration_c[0][1] and $duration_c[1][0]+$duration_c[1][1], and how to print?
there is error **Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

Comment: what is the value of $k and $s in $times=$duration_c[$k][$s]; statement

Comment: I see you are new on SO, and I've observed that 95% of the new users tend to not accept one of the answers. Please look at them and accept the one that fits your needs best, by checking the mark "accept this answer" beneath the voting arrows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are sending only one value to sum_the_time function as `$times=$duration_c[$k][$s];`
$times has only one value you can print and check what value is going to the function by writing like this

```
$times=$duration_c[$k][$s];
echo $times;
```

use

```
$times=$duration_c[$k];
```

so that you can send array to your function and foreach will not give you error

```
$times=$duration_c[$k]; // contains array of times
function sum_the_time($times) {

  $seconds = 0;
  foreach ($times as $time)
  {
    list($hour,$minute,$second) = explode(':', $time);
    $seconds += $hour*3600;
    $seconds += $minute*60;
    $seconds += $second;
 }
  $hours = floor($seconds/3600);
  $seconds -= $hours*3600;
  $minutes  = floor($seconds/60);
  $seconds -= $minutes*60;
  // return "{$hours}:{$minutes}:{$seconds}";
  return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
} 
echo sum_the_time($times);
```

Comment: is it giving proper values now

Answer (score 1):

This does it less in PHP code, and keeps the execution flow as much as possibly in the PHP runtime, written in C:

```
<?php
$duration_c[0][0]="19:30:00";
$duration_c[0][1]="00:10:00";

$duration_c[1][0]="00:30:00";
$duration_c[1][1]="00:20:00";

$sum = 0;
foreach($duration_c as $durations) {
    $today = strtotime('today');
    $sum += array_sum(array_map(function($str) use ($today) {
        return strtotime($str)-$today;
    }, $durations));
}
echo $sum; // 73800 seconds, that's 20.5 hours
```

Answer (score 0):

`$times=$duration_c[$k][$s];` should be `$times=$duration_c[$k];`, otherwise you are passing a single time to the function, not an array of times.